# How to give regex pattern in scope of angular js

Tags: regex, angularjs, validation, ng-pattern

I have an input field which looks like

```
 <input class="inputMargin urlInputWidth" type="text" size="40" name="url" ng-model="user.customerId" maxlength="250" ng-pattern="/sftp://.+/" />
```

It works fine and shows validation as expected. I just wanted to move this pattern to scope of angularjs to get a much neater form. I have tried with this syntax: `$scope.sftpValidate="/sftp://.+/";` and `ng-pattern="sftpValidate"`. But this is not validating the pattern at all. i have tried to give as `$scope.sftpValidate=/sftp://.+/;` and `$scope.sftpValidate=sftp://.+;`. But these are showing syntax errors. Where am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/renegica/1/edit)

View:

```
<input class="inputMargin urlInputWidth" type="text" size="40" name="url" ng-model="user.customerId" maxlength="250" ng-pattern="regex " />
```

JS

```
$scope.regex = /sftp://.+/;
```

JS UPDATED BY sms:

```
$scope.regex = /sftp:\/\/.+/;
```

Comment: For the pattern given in your example its working fine. But for my pattern it is showing syntax expression. Am i missing any escape sequences?

Comment: I have updated JS in your answer and marked as answer. I have just missed escape char for forward slash. "$scope.regex = /sftp:\/\/.+/;"